# Trying to get only the animations from a GLTF file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gltf

I would like to obtain from every kind of gltfAsset only the animations in it to create an animation file. Someone know if a library can help me or if there is a easiest way to do it ?

```
private async createAnimationAssets(props: Props, animations: Animation[]): Promise<CreateMetaAssetResponseDto[]> {
    const animationAssets = await Promise.all(
      animations.map(async (animation) => {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
          try {
            const asset = await this.assetRepository.create(
              new MetaBuilderAssetListItem({
                createdAt: this.dateService.now(),
                modifiedAt: this.dateService.now(),
                id: undefined,
                projectId: props.projectId,
                name: animation.name,
                type: "animation",
                exclude: false,
              })
            );
            if (!asset.id) return reject();
            const assetData: MetaAsset = MetaBuilderAssetMapper.defaultAsset({
              ...props,
              name: animation.name || "",
              assetId: asset.id,
              source: false,
              type: "animation",
            });
            if (props.parent) await this.insertParentPath(assetData, props.parent);
            // créer le fichier glb ui ne contient que l'animation
            const gltfAsset = fsExtra.readFileSync(`temp/${assetData.file?.filename}`);

            // const gltfAnimations = 

            gltfPipeline.gltfToGlb(gltfAnimations).then(function (results: any) {
              fsExtra.writeFileSync(`${animation.name}.glb`, results.glb);
            });
            console.log(`gltfAsset: ${gltfAsset}`);
            // lire les meta-données de mon fichier
            assetData.file = {
              filename: animation.name,
              size: 0,
              hash: assetData.file?.hash,
            };
            // console.log(assetData);
            await this.sharedbSocket.insertDoc(`assets`, asset.id, assetData);
            const response: CreateMetaAssetResponseDto = {
              ...assetData,
              id: +asset.id,
              uniqueId: +asset.id,
              createdAt: asset.createdAt,
              modifiedAt: asset.modifiedAt,
            };
            console.log(response);
            this.sharedbSocket.emitAssetCreated(response);
            return resolve(response);
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return reject(err);
          }
        });
      })
    );
    return animationAssets.filter((asset) => asset) as CreateMetaAssetResponseDto[];
  }
```

> 

if you need any additional information to help me do not hesitate to say me !

Comment: Canyou specify what kind of format is `animation[]` and the structure of GLTF asset

Comment: > interface Target {
  node: number;
  path: string;
}

interface Channel {
  sampler: number;
  target: Target;
}

export interface Animation {
  name: string;
  Channels: Channel[];
  samplers: Sampler[];
}

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/files/gltf20-reference-guide.pdf

Comment: @jomaup by "create an animation file", do you mean that you want to put raw keyframe data somewhere? Or you want to create a new glTF file, containing the animations and nothing else? I don't think I know what the "MetaAsset" stuff is in the code you shared.

Comment: Yes, i try to create a new gltf file which contains only the animations.

Comment: export interface MetaAsset {
  assetId?: string;
  task?: string;
  projectId?: string;
  type: string;
  source_asset_id?: string;
  user_id?: number;
  item_id?: number;
 tags?: string[];
  revision?: number;
  region?: string;
  path?: number[];
  i18n?: any;
  has_thumbnail?: boolean;
  checkpoint_id?: string;
  name: string;
  preload: boolean | string;
  branchId: string;
  data: any;
  meta?: any;
  source: boolean;
  file?: MetaAssetFile;
  scope?: {
            type: string;
            id: number;
        }
    }

Comment: this is a default format of assets to save every kind of assets that we receive in our database

Comment: Ok thanks — added a longer answer below. I'll let you figure out how to put the data into that MetaAsset, as I don't know anything about that. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using [glTF Transform](https://gltf-transform.donmccurdy.com/) to extract data from, or modify, glTF files in a Node.js environment.

Start by reading the file with [NodeIO](https://gltf-transform.donmccurdy.com/classes/core.nodeio.html):

```js
import { NodeIO } from '@gltf-transform/core';
import { KHRONOS_EXTENSIONS } from '@gltf-transform/extensions';

const io = new NodeIO().registerExtensions( KHRONOS_EXTENSIONS );

// (a) read from disk
const document = await io.read('path/to/scene.glb');

// (b) read from memory
const document = await io.readBinary(glb); // glb is Uint8Array or Buffer
```

Next we'll make type definitions to hold the new animation data, if you're using TypeScript.

```js
interface Clip {
    name: string,
    tracks: Track[],
}

interface Track {
    targetObject: string,
    targetProperty: string, // 'translation', 'rotation', 'scale', 'weights'
    interpolation: string, // 'LINEAR', 'CUBICSPLINE', 'STEP'
    times: number[],
    values: number[]
}
```

Then, parse the animation data from the glTF [Animations](https://gltf-transform.donmccurdy.com/classes/core.animation.html), into these structures:

```js
const clips = [] as Clip[];

for (const animation of document.getRoot().listAnimations()) {
    const tracks = [];

    for (const channel of animation.listChannels()) {
        const sampler = channel.getSampler();
        tracks.push({
            targetObject: channel.getTargetNode().getName(),
            targetProperty: channel.getTargetPath(),
            interpolation: sampler.getInterpolation(),
            times: Array.from(sampler.getInput().getArray()),
            values: Array.from(sampler.getOutput().getArray())
        } as Track)
    }

    clips.push({ name: animation.getName(), tracks: tracks } as Clip);
}

console.log(clips);
```

You can do whatever you want with that clips data - it represents the raw keyframes, with each track identifying the object it affects by name. This does require that your glTF file have unique names for animated objects.

If you'd rather not write raw data, but just have a new glTF file containing nothing but the animation, you can also do that instead:

```js
import { prune } from '@gltf-transform/functions';

// remove all mesh data
for (const mesh of document.getRoot().listMeshes()) {
    for (const prim of mesh.listPrimitives()) {
        prim.dispose();
    }
}

// clean up unused materials, textures, ...
await document.transform(prune());

// (a) write to disk
await io.write('path/to/output.glb', document);

// (b) write to bytes
const bytes = await io.writeBinary(document);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches, but I tell you my workflow

you are trying to extract the animation data from a GLTF file, convert it to a GLB format, and then save it as a new file.
The library 'gltf-pipeline' can be used to convert GLTF to GLB. The gltfToGlb function from the library takes a GLTF object and returns a promise that resolves with the GLB data.

Library link here https://github.com/CesiumGS/gltf-pipeline

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's what i am doing below but before i want to extract from the gltf file only the animations to create an animation file